# ViewData and ViewModel in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, view, controller, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm new to .Net development, and now are following NerdDinner tutorial. Just wondering if any of you would be able to tell me

> What is the differences between ViewData
>   and ViewModel

(all I know is they are used to pass some form of data from controller to view) and perhaps tell me on what situation should I use ViewData instead of ViewModel and vice versa

Thanks in advance!

Sally

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**ViewData:**

In short, use ViewData as support data, such as a datasource to a SelectList.

**ViewModel:**

[ASP.NET MVC ViewModel Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361092/asp-net-mvc-viewmodel-pattern)

> When a Controller class decides to render an HTML response back to a
>   client, it is responsible for
>   explicitly passing to the view
>   template all of the data needed to
>   render the response. View templates
>   should never perform any data
>   retrieval or application logic – and
>   should instead limit themselves to
>   only have rendering code that is
>   driven off of the model/data passed to
>   it by the controller.
>
> [...]
>
> When using [the "ViewModel"] pattern we create strongly-typed
>   classes that are optimized for our
>   specific view scenarios, and which
>   expose properties for the dynamic
>   values/content needed by our view
>   templates. Our controller classes can
>   then populate and pass these
>   view-optimized classes to our view
>   template to use. This enables
>   type-safety, compile-time checking,
>   and editor intellisense within view
>   templates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, incase anyone need to know more about this topic I also found a great blog entry relating to my question http://theminimalistdeveloper.com/2010/08/21/why-when-and-how-to-use-typed-views-and-viewmodel-pattern-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 12):

**What is ViewData ?**

- dictionary object that you put data into, which then becomes
  available to the view.

***ViewData Sample***

**Controller Action method likes :**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var featuredProduct = new Product
        {
            Name = "Smart Phone",
            QtyOnHand = 12
        };

        ViewData["FeaturedProduct"] = featuredProduct;
        return View();
    }
}
```

**How to use ViewData on View ?**

```
@{    
    var viewDataProduct = ViewData["FeaturedProduct"] as Product;
 }
<div>
    Today's Featured Product is!
    <h3>@viewDataProduct.Name</h3>
</div>
```

**What is a ViewModel ?**

- Allow you to shape multiple entities from one or more data models or
  sources into a single object
- Optimized for consumption and rendering by the view

**Its like :**

[image: View Model image]

**How to use ViewModel with MVC 3 ?**

**Domain Model**

```
public class Product
    {
        public Product() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); Created = DateTime.Now; }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public Guid VmId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

    }
```

**Controller Action Method**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddProduct()
{
    //for initialize viewmodel
    var productViewModel = new ProductViewModel();

    //assign values for viewmodel
    productViewModel.ProductName = "Smart Phone";

    //send viewmodel into UI (View)
    return View("AddProduct", productViewModel);
}
```

**View - AddProduct.cshtml**

```
@model YourProject.ViewModels.ProductViewModel //set your viewmodel here
```

**Conclusion**

- By using ViewModel can pass strongly-typed data into View
- But ViewData is Loosely Typed.So Need to cast data on View
- ViewModel can use for Complex scenarios such as merging more than one
  domain model
- But ViewData can be used only for simple scenarios like bring data
  for the drop down list
- ViewModel can use for attribute-based validation scenarios which
  needed for Ui
- But Cannot use ViewData for such kind of validations
- As a best practices always try to use strongly typed data with
  Views.ViewModel is the best candidate for that.

Comment: I often find it cleaner to load your needed domain models into the ViewModel as private members and expose what you actually want for the view through properties. Also, if you set it up like an adapter, the data returned from the view through the viewmodel could then, in turn, hydrate data on the hidden domain objects.