# POST returns Http 400 Bad request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-400

When I make a POST request to ASP.NET MVC app, I'm getting HTTP 400 Bad Request.
I have decorated  the post action with `[ValidateInput(false)]`, but still i am getting this error.

I have a model which is the parameter of the POST method.

Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Please provide more details. For example, does an exception get thrown by your MVC application?

Comment: Please post sample code of your application to give us a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: A 400 means there is something wrong with your request.  Usually something is malformed or too large.  Without more info, we can't really say what...

Comment: i hosted this in IIS and i came to see that its working fine. It was giving the issue asp.net development server.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Model as parameter to action, use [Viewmodel Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361092/asp-net-mvc-viewmodel-pattern), it will be much clearer  what data you post. Post the code of the View, and the code of the Model.